# Why .ipkg format is mainly considered for the embedded devices...?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, webos, package-management

Im new to the yocto and webos development, in webos the final output image is in .ipk package format..

I tried to figure out that why .ipk package format is used or preferred for the embedded devices compared to the .rpm or .deb .

And I finally ended up with the answers like it is used for embedded devices mainly because they have space constraints etc ..,

But I didn't got what are the in depth differences of those packages and why they are preferable for the embedded devices...

Comment: Here is said that they are almost similar but ipk uses tar and deb uses ar (which was just easier to implement) http://lists.openmoko.org/pipermail/devel/2008-July/000496.html

Answer (score 3):

.ipk and .deb packages are pretty much the same thing at this point.

Its more that opkg, the package manager which handles .ipk packages is considered to be an embedded system package manager. Systems with dpkg+apt or rpm+dnf or other similar combinations are usually larger with higher system requirements.